# configure php from Redhat to connect to MS SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, redhat, moodle

I'm trying to deploy Moodle LMS on Redhat server with php56 and I want to connect it to another remote MS SQL server through freetds and php-mssql,How to configure them together to be able to connect the Moodle LMS to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you installed all needed packages (php-mssql and freetds).
You have to add an entry in /etc/freetds.conf like this:

```
[mydb]
       host = 10.0.0.199
       port = 1433
       tds version = 8.0
       client charset = UTF-8
       text size = 20971520
```

Restart httpd (service httpd restart)
Then in moodle set db name to mydb and everything will work.
It could be that you will have to set/disable selinux for moodle. do this temporarily in this way :

```
setenforce 0
```

Then edit /etc/selinuc/config for next boot.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks Yedidia,I tried that before and didn't work also, moodle still give me the error database driver problem detected, is there is any configuration to set for /etc/odbc.ini or any work around to make moodle be able to connect with php mssql driver like configuring php.ini?

Comment: there is no need to touch php.ini, could u plz list all your php packages ? rpm -ql | grep php . did you restated httpd ?

Comment: yes I did restart the service, the installed service are as follows all starts with php56w  (cli , common, devel, gd, intl, mbstring, mcrypt, mssql, mysql, odbc, opcache, pdo, xml) I tried to remove them and reinstall also the same problem?

Comment: do you get any error ? is the mssql option listed during installation ? there are two mssql drivers -  one is named mssql and second is sqlsrv that is windows only.. are you able to connect to mssql via cli and tsql ? here is the syntax for tsql :  tsql -H server_address -p 1433 -U user -P pass -D dbname

Comment: I was able to connect with tsql , mssql is installed it appears that the php or moodle can't connect to the mssql driver to the remote host, I'm not sure if it's in the configuration of any of php or moodle.

Comment: Error: database drive problem detected

Comment: Error: database drive problem detected
The site administrator should verify server configuration
Microsoft Drivers for SQL Server for PHP are available only for Windows OS.

Comment: selinux ? what's the output of getenforce ?

Comment: selinux is disabled on the server.

Comment: write a simple php file in /var/www/html that has only this line : <?php phpinfo(); then see via browser if mssql is there...

Comment: yes, it exists in the info page.
I have an issue I tried to connect with tsql using -H server.name and using -S mydb and both worked for me. the issue seems to be from somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks Yedidia for your effort and Help, it appeared the problem was in moodle config file I kept the old one with the old parameters :-)